# vertical centering of list items

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have read many articles about vertical centering but I’m afraid not many of them are intuitive, hence unable to apply it to my problem. Basically, I have a main div and in there, I’ve got unordered list which has an image and paragraph tag within it and are displayed using inline-block. This aspect of the work is fine.

The problem or what I am trying to achieve is to have the list centered in the middle of the screen. So for instance, if I have got just one item in the list, it should be in the middle and then move upwards as more items are entered in the list.

```
<div id = "main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="test.jpg" alt="#" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>          
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#main {
    margin: 60px auto;
    height: 400px;
} 
#main ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 13px 72px 22px;
    height: 100px;  
}

#main ul { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but here is a possible solution. The trick to this is the line-height.

EDIT: This should do it...

http://jsfiddle.net/cxmsr/4/

```
#main
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #999999;
    display: table;
}
#main UL
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#main LI
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 2px 2px 6px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You can change the #main width to 100% or whatever you need.

Comment: @wdm, thanks. what i am trying to achieve is quite similar to what you have provided but there are two problems, when you add alot more list items, then it looks something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cxmsr/3/")

Comment: ok, i fixed that by adding line-height: 1 to the ul, but i can no longer use vertical-align:top which i need to properly position the items.. :(

Comment: I can prob solve your problem but i'm still kind of unsure of what exactly you're going for. I understand you want to have a horiz row of boxes but do you want just one row or several rows? I think you're first comment is concerning them dropping to a 2nd row and being widely spaced. So did you want close rows in the center?

Comment: I want several rows which are closely spaced in the center but only mentioned one for the purpose of simplicity. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Perfect..it worked perfectly...also found something similar      [here](http://www.gobdg.com/blog/2009/05/vertical-horizontal-centering-w-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution. I've added borders to make the result easier to see.

```
    #main {
        margin: 60px auto;
        height:600px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border:1px solid #d0d0d0
    } 



    #main ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 13px 72px 22px;
        height: 100px;
        border:1px solid #ff0000; 
}
```

Comment: apologies if i did not explain myself properly but the solution provided is not quite what i need in that, the list displays horizontally but i want it to start in the middle of the page. with the code you've provided, the list is displayed vertically and not centered

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the flexible box model in css3: http://jsfiddle.net/zgzct/1/

The spec for the flexbox just changed quite a bit and browser support isn't consistent so go with Diodeus' solution if it works for you.